# getline with an input file using a function, array and structure

Tags: c++, getline

I am writing a program for my class that takes a text file and has each line in the text assigned.The problem i am having is that when i use the getline() its completely skipping the input. From everything i have read i feel like i am doing it right but obviously i am missing something.This is a small part of the code...if you need the whole thing i can post it.Thanks ahead of time for everyone's help.

```
garage populategarage()
{
garage tg; //temporary garage
string instruction_prompt;

initialize_garage(tg);
ifstream inputFile;

inputFile.open("garage-input-file.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_VEHICLES; i++)
{
    inputFile >> tg.vehicles[i].category;


    if (tg.vehicles[i].category == "\0")
        i = NUM_OF_VEHICLES;
    else
    {
        inputFile >> tg.vehicles[i].make;

        inputFile >> tg.vehicles[i].model;

        inputFile >> tg.vehicles[i].color;

        inputFile >> tg.vehicles[i].year;

        inputFile >> tg.vehicles[i].trans;

        inputFile >> tg.vehicles[i].cylinder;

        getline(inputFile, tg.vehicles[i].drive); //This is my problem

    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the `C++` tag and check the line at the top of your code that looks like a stray. (e.g. `garage populategarage() { garage tg; //temporary garage string instruction_prompt;`)

Comment: The rest of this code seems to work fine just for some reason with the .drive   line it just completely skips it as an input and runs the loop again causing the display to be off by one place.Am i missing something as far as the getline is concerned or does that look right?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any example input, or what your results are, but from your description it seems like each value appears on its own line.  Would that be right?  In that case, the `getline` call is likely to be picking up the *previous* newline (from when you read `cylinder`), and returning an empty string.

If your values appear on separate lines, you should probably use `getline` for each.  You can wrap this behaviour for any type into a template function - something simple like:

```
template <class T>
istream & readValue( istream & s, T & value )
{
    string line;
    if( getline( s, line ) )
    {
        istringstream iss( line );
        iss >> value;
    }
    return s;
}
```

If instead your file contains a *single* line for each entry, then it's usually better to use `getline` for the whole line, then read individual values from an `istringstream`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_VEHICLES; i++)
{
    string line;
    if( !getline( inputFile, line ) ) break;
    istringstream iss( line );

    iss >> tg.vehicles[i].make;
    iss >> tg.vehicles[i].model;
    // etc...
}
```